# Java Swing - position panel in top left of a JTabbedframe

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout, jtabbedpane

I am having to migrate from Python TKinter to Java Swing due to a change of jobs.

The problem I have is:

How do I position a panel containing objects such as labels and text fields in the top left hand corner of `JTabbedFrame`.

If the frame itself is bigger than the panel , the `JPanel` is centering by default on the page.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class GUI {

    //Constructor
    GUI(){
        //Craete a new frame
        //borderlayout
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Tabbed Demo");            
        //Intialize size
        jfrm.setSize(500, 250);         
        //Terminate program 
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
        //Create Tabbed Frame
        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);         
        //Create a panel to place on tabbed page
        JPanel jpnl = new JPanel();
        jpnl.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);           
        jpnl.setOpaque(true);
        jpnl.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        //create a 3 labels horizontally            
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        JLabel title= new JLabel(" Tracking System   ");
        title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        jpnl.add(title,gbc);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=1;    
        JLabel subtitle= new JLabel("First");
        subtitle.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        jpnl.add(subtitle,gbc);
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=1;
        JTextArea firstText = new JTextArea("Type Here!");
        firstText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        jpnl.add(firstText,gbc);            
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=2;            
        JLabel subtitle2= new JLabel("Last");
        jpnl.add(subtitle2,gbc);
        subtitle2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));           
        //add to Tab
        jtp.addTab("Demo", jpnl);           
        //make visible
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jtp);         
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // launch app

        //create the frame on the event dispaytching thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new GUI();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

The result is shown below

[image]

What I want to do is move the location of the `JPanel` to the top left no matter how big the frame is, eg location 0,0 of the tabbed page.Override the centring of the `JPanel`.

I am using the `GridBaglayout` manager.

Comment: GridBagLayout kinda sucks.  I'd recommend using MigLayout instead.  It can do everything that GBL can and a lot more, and is a lot more succinct and manageable to work with.

Comment: Are there any good tutorials on MIGLayout you can supply a link for

Comment: Just check out the quick start guide and cheat sheet at the home page: http://www.miglayout.com/

Comment: You can achieve this using GridBagLayout by setting the weightx and weighty properties of the last component

Answer (score 2):

Not to discount the power of something like MigLayout, but if you're stuck on a project which limits third party libraries, then knowing how to manipulate the default layout managers is one of the most important skills you can develop

You could simply add a "filler" component into you layout, setting it's `weightx` and `weighty` properties to fill the available space

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2; //GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

            JLabel title = new JLabel("Tracking System");
            title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(40f));
            add(title, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("First: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("First: "), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            // Blank/filler component
            add(new JLabel(), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

By changing

```
gbc.gridwidth = 2; //GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
```

to

```
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
```

I can effect the position of the `title` as well

[image: Title position]

But you can also effect it by using the `anchor` property.  Which you use will come down to your needs

Have a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details